# JOptionPane dialogs causing JavaFX stage to be "not responding"

Tags: java, swing, javafx-8, joptionpane, freeze

I have a JavaFX window (subclass of [Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)) which lets [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) dialog boxes be opened from it. For example, a confirmation dialog is opened like this when the user clicks a specific menu option:

```
int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title,
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
// do something based on the choice...
```

The problem is, when the dialog is open, clicking on the JavaFX window causes Windows to think it's "not responding" and make it fade into white. However, after closing the dialog box the window goes back to normal. This behaviour is mostly correct as users shouldn't be able to interact with the window until the dialog has been closed, but the window shouldn't appear to crash if they click on it.

I'm not sure what the solution to this is. Could the window thread be paused until the JOptionPane method returns?

Comment: May I ask why you are using `JOptionPane` instead of [`Alert`](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)?

Comment: I haven't heard of that before, looks good. Shame it requires JDK 8u40; my project is using JDK 8u31. This is for a university dissertation project which is due in a couple of days, so I don't want to update Java or make any large changes which might create new bugs!

Comment: I advise the you update to Java 8u40 and use Alert anyway, or, failing that, replace the usage of JOptionPane with a JavaFX only solution which works with your chosen JavaFX version (there are many of these available if you search stackoverflow for JavaFX Dialog).

Comment: If you are allowed to, you could also use the openjfx-dialogs (small footprint). They are bundled with [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) and will work regardless of your Java update.

Comment: If you use `JOptionPane`, you need to do so on the AWT event dispatch thread. If this is a JavaFX Application, you are calling this on the FX Application Thread. You need to manage multiple threads if you are going to do it this way (which is one reason you are being encouraged to find a JavaFX solution).